# Is this a valid attempt at the Riemann Hypothesis?

Tags: proof-verification, approximation, riemann-hypothesis

From Marcus Du Sautoy's book “The music of the primes”, there is a method of finding a very long list of N consecutive numbers which are not primes. e.g $101!+2, 101!+3,...,101!+101$ all of which are not primes $(N=100)$.
In general $(N+1)!+2$ to $(N+1)!+N+1$ are not primes.

This means $\pi((N+1)!+1)$ to $\pi((N+1)!+N+1)$ is a flat line on the graph of $\pi(x)$ for however long N is.

The main arguments for this attempt at the Riemann Hypothesis is based on

1. An equivalent to the Riemann Hypothesis which states that $$|\text{Li}(x)-\pi(x)|\le c\sqrt{x}\ln x$$ i.e. $Li(x)$ is a good approximation of $\pi(x)$ *1
2. The idea that if Li($x$) is a bad approximation of $\pi(x)$ then when an unimaginably long extended flat line of $\pi(x)$ occurs then Li($x$) should at one point cease to be a good approximation.

Going forward let $\beta$ = (N+1)! and it follows that $\beta + 1$ is the start of our flat line

We would first consider $$\text{Li}(\beta+1) > \pi(\beta+1).$$ {1} Drawing a sketch yourself would most likely help to understand the following steps.
We hope to show that $$\text{Li}(\beta+n) - \pi(\beta+n) \le c\sqrt{\beta+n}\ln(\beta+n) (1) $$ where $n$ is any integer $\le N+1$

We would also now assume that $$\text{Li}(\beta+1) - \pi(\beta+1) \le c\sqrt{\beta+1}\ln(\beta+1)$$ i.e. the beginning of our flat line and so this is a reasonable assumption as we are saying the Riemann hypothesis is true until now.
Then consider and assume (like in induction) $$\text{Li}(\beta+k) - \pi(\beta+k) \le c\sqrt{\beta+k}\ln(\beta+k)   (2)$$ 
For $n = k+1 $
$$\text{Li}(\beta+k+1) - \pi(\beta+k+1) = \text{Li}(\beta+k) - \pi(\beta+k) +(\text{Li}(\beta+k+1) - \text{Li}(\beta+k)) (3) $$note: $\pi(\beta+k+1) = \pi(\beta+k)$ as we are still in the flat line region.

Remembering the $\beta =(N+1)!$ If we make N large enough $$\text{Li}(\beta +k+1)-\text{Li}(\beta+k) \approx 0$$
Therefore it is safe to say that $$\text{Li}(\beta+k+1) - \pi(\beta+k+1) \leq c\sqrt{\beta+k+1}\ln(\beta+k+1)$$The worst case is that $\text{Li}(\beta+k) - \pi(\beta+k) = c\sqrt{\beta+k}ln(\beta+k)$ which using (3) which implies 
$$\text{Li}(\beta+k+1) - \text{Li}(\beta+k) \leq c\sqrt{\beta+k+1}\ln(\beta+k+1) - c\sqrt{\beta+k}\ln(\beta+k)$$
However both sides tend to zero for large $N$

So it is perhaps fair to conclude that if (1) is true for $n=k+1$ it is also true for n=k+1 and as we started with saying it was true for $n=1$ it must also be true for $n \leq N+1$

If $$\text{Li}(\beta+1) = \pi(\beta+1) $$ {2} then the argument is the same as above

However what if $$\pi(\beta+1) > \text{Li}(\beta+1)  $$ {3}
While  as we can make $N$ as large as we want then we can be sure Li($x$) would eventually cross $\pi(x)$ and then we can a apply the argument for both {1} and {2} from the point where they cross

Eventually going back to our main argument 2 above we see that even in the most likely condition for Li($x$) to be a bad approximation it doesn't do so, which implies Li($x$) is a good approximation of $\pi(x)$

*1 Weisstein, Eric W. "Prime Number Theorem." From MathWorld--A Wolfram Web Resource.

Comment: The answer to the question in the title is, No.

Comment: @Gerry Myerson Why? If you don't mind we asking

Comment: Because if there were a proof at this level, Riemann would have found it.

Comment: I don't mind being told that its wrong but can you please or someone else help to point out where the error is. Bearing in mind that I am not yet in uni (I'm in A levels).

Comment: Then it's good practice for you to find the error. That's most of what mathematicians do, is find the mistakes in their own work.

Comment: @GerryMyerson The set of all candidate proofs at this level is certainly too big for anybody to go through all of them to see that none of them work. So you suggesting that it would have been found if it existed seems more like a guess than a fact.

Comment: @kasperd I'm sure you don't believe that mathematicians work by trying every proof from a vast collection of possible candidates.

Comment: To add on what @Gerry wrote; if you have to ask on a general math website if your half-page of math is a valid proof of one of the major open problems in modern mathematics, the answer is - and should be - no.

Comment: @KevinCarlson No, but I believe a mathematician wouldn't claim no such proof exists without being able to prove it.

Comment: This really isn't a good site for posting results under the guise of asking, "Is this correct?" Generally, that indicates you are working on your own, completely divorced from people who do mathematics.

Comment: @kasperd Not every claim mathematicians make about mathematics is a mathematical claim. Sometimes we're also humans speaking in English about a human activity.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is asserting proof of a well-known open problem.

Comment: If you successfully define precisely what you mean by "good approximation" you will see why this 'proof attempt' is doomed.

Comment: @user21820 The phrase good approximation is taken from Barry Mazur and W.Stein's book http://wstein.org/rh/rh.pdf pg 43 and for its relation to an equivalent to the Riemann Hypothesis you can see Chapter 13 pg 47. Thanks.

Comment: @user215395: You don't understand. There is no such thing as "good approximation" unless you define it precisely. An approximation always has to come with precise error estimates, otherwise I can say that π is approximately 4 which is just as meaningless as saying that π is about 0. Any meaningless statement by 'virtue' of being meaningless cannot be proven. "$π \in [3,4]$" on the other hand is a meaningful statement that can potentially be proven. By the way, it does not matter who says what in mathematics; it only matters whether a statement is meaningful and a proof rigorous or not.

Comment: @user215395: I hope you get what I'm trying to say, because precision is very important in mathematics, which is not about vague statements such as you have in philosophy. Everything in mathematics must have a perfectly precise meaning, so that it is either provably true, provably false, or unprovable. If it cannot be defined precisely, it is not even fit to be a hypothesis, though it can suggest various lines of exploration. For example, some of Hilbert's list of problems are not precise. Some are true under a certain (precise) interpretation but false under others.

Comment: @user21820 there are several reasons why the proof will never work, but "good approximation" actually *is* defined reasonably precisely (it is not perfect but that part is actually coherent).

Comment: @quid: Of course people can make it precise. But the asker seems to have been using "approximation" in the loose non-mathematical sense in the proof attempt. Specifically, the structure of quantifiers have all disappeared. Once everything is made precise with full quantification and the proof attempted in formal logic it will become obvious why it doesn't work. It is just like if I say that a function is continuous if one gets approximately the same output for approximately the same input, namely $|f(x)-f(y)|<ε$ for sufficiently close $x,y$. Same ambiguity as here.

Comment: @user21820 once again this part is reasonably precise (teh sole quantifier that is missing is an "exists" for the $c$ but really this is a nit-pick ). The problem lies elsewhere.

Comment: @quid: Are you sure you understand logic **properly**? Of course the whole piece is full of problems, which is why I said "Once everything is made precise with full quantification and the proof attempted in formal logic ...". My point is that if one cannot even get the statement to be proven quantified right (the order of quantification over $c$ and $x$ matters!!!), one is bound to fail in the proof attempt (and indeed, we see "$\text{Li}(\beta +k+1)-\text{Li}(\beta+k) \approx 0$" halfway down with $\approx$ having no meaning whatsoever, and also the induction is logically completely wrong.

Comment: @quid: If it is still not clear, to use induction you need to first define a predicate $P$ and then prove $P(0)$ and $\forall k\in\mathbb{N} ( P(k) \rightarrow P(k+1) )$. The asker failed to do so precisely because he did not understand the logical structure of induction and essentially failed to even define $P$, since whatever could possibly be interpreted as $P$ in his 'proof attempt' was being changed throughout as he changed $N$ and hence $β$.

Comment: @quid: Actually I'm hoping that you do know logic but just don't think it's important to state things precisely. If so I can tell you that lack of precision is the one biggest reason why students in general do not understand mathematics. You see tons of questions like "why do we invert fractions when dividing" or "when do we use proof by contrapositive?" all of which point at the same problem. So I hope you understand where I'm coming from. Programmers can write syntactically perfect code because the compiler forces them to. Math students can't write formal proofs because no one makes them!

Answer (score 25):

It would theoretically be possible to disprove the Riemann Hypothesis by establishing the existence of a 'too long' string of composite numbers.

However, this 'too long' needs to be taken in a relative sense, that is relative to the size of the elements in the string. And, in your example the elements are huge relative to the length of the string.

Answer (score 25):

Roughly speaking, according to the Prime Number Theorem, in the region of $x$, on average one integer out of every $\log x$ is prime. Now, Stirling's approximation says that $\log n!$ is roughly $n\log n$; so in the region of $n!$, you would expect one in every $n\log n$ numbers to be prime. This is less than one in every $n$.

So to find a run of composite integers of length $n$ in the region of $n!$ is nothing special; in fact, we would expect to find runs of length $n \log n$ and more without having to look hard.